# Is generating function defined for every possible sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

For every converging series surely it is, but how about $a_n=2^{2^n}$? Is $f(x)=\sum_{n>=0}2^{2^n}x^n$ well defined? It actually converges only for x=0, but my intuition says it is somehow not well defined. If it's perfectly fine to make generating function of $a_n=2^{2^n}$ is there some other weird seqence that generating function is not defined for?

Comment: There is a notion of a "formal power series." Given any commutative ring, $R,$ we can form the ring of formal power series, $R[[x]],$ and we don't need to worry about convergence. Essentially, we are treating $x$ as an indeterminate such that $x^n$ goes to zero "fast enough" for all sequences. The ring of power series can be though of as the inverse limit of $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^n\rangle.$

Comment: In the ring of formal power series, you get: $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i =\frac{1}{1-x}.$$ not just as a function, for $|x|<1.$ but in terms of ring inverses. $1-x$ is the multiplicative inverse of the left side in $R[[x]].$

Comment: The surprise is you don't even need $R$ to have a notion of convergence at all to talk about the ring of power series. $R=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is perfectly allowed. To the extent that we can 'evaluate' a formal power series, we can compose $p(q(x))$ for any $p\in R[[x]]$ and $q\in xR[[x]],$ but we can't evaluate $p$ at a general $q\in R[[x]].$